# Is it valid to have XML attributes on newlines?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, sublimetext

I know that you can have newlines inside your `XML attributes`. But can you put each attribute on its own line?

```
<maritalStatusCode
  code="M"
  displayName="Married"
  codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.2"
  codeSystemName="MaritalStatusCode"/>
```

In **Sublime** it shows up as a `non-closing tag`. And when I try to parse it with something like jsdom it breaks there as well. I've tried googling this but haven't found a definitive answer yet. I can provide more info on the document if needed. I'm not super well versed in all the intricacies of XML so I may have left out pertinent information.

Comment: Interesting question indeed.
HTML allows this, especially when you use angularjs, which makes you add a lot of attributes on a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, line-breaks within an XML element are absolutely fine.
Perhaps you are moving between Windows and Unix, and the difference in line-breaks is tripping up the parsers?

Comment: This solved the issue. Converting everything from CRLF to LF makes jsdom happy it seems.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [this BNF grammar for XML](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/xmlgrammar/), it appears that newlines and carriage returns within a tag are fine. Tags can include white space (`S`), and the definition of white space includes `0xA` and `0xD`, which are NL and CR, respectively.

Tools that generate XML could be more restrictive and still be correct in the sense that they generate correct XML, but tools that accept XML should accept tags with line breaks.